# Node partial require/import

Tags: node.js

I am following a MS tutorials on node and trying to require part of the module only. When i execute the code i get a syntax error though VS code editor seems to import properly in intellisense. Please assist

Index.js

```
'use strict';

const { doSomething }  = require('./first-module');
doSomething();
```

first-module.js

```
module.exports = {
    doIt: function(){
        console.log('Did it');
    },
    doSomething: function(){
        console.log('Did Something');
    },
    getItDone: function(){
        console.log('Got it done');
    }
};
```

Terminal Error: Running with "node index"

```
d:\env\node\first-module>node index                                                                                                    
d:\env\node\first-module\index.js:3                                                                                                    
const { doSomething }  = require('./first-module');                                                                                    
      ^                                                                                                                                

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {                                                                                                        
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)                                                                                          
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)                                                                                              
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)                                                                                
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)                                                                                                  
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)                                                                                        
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)                                                                                      
    at startup (node.js:139:18)                                                                                                        
    at node.js:974:3
```

In the tutorial, however, the result was diplaying 'Did Something' in the console.

Comment: Are you running a babelized version, using babel-cli, etc?

Comment: @DaveNewton : I am not using babel transpiler. I wrote the code in VS code IDE and using the internal console terminal for testing. Updating my node environment did fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newest version of stable node (6.7.0) supports using the syntax you specified.
So I recommend updating..